# How to get font of widget in Qt set by stylesheet?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qtstylesheets

I have Qt application with custom stylesheet applied to it (and for all widgets in general) with custom font included in this stylesheet. But when try to get font of some widget `font()` method return different font. I want to get the font of a `QWidget` which is set by a stylesheet. The `font()` method always returns the global system font or the font set by `setFont()`, but not the font which is set by `setStyleSheet()` and is used for painting in the widget. I need the font to do some calculations based on the font size. I use Qt 4.6. How can I get real font of widget (that is showing when application run) set by stylesheet?

After some investigations I saw that if I apply defined stylesheet to some widget I can get proper font information (defined by stylesheet) with `myWidget->font()` method. Also when I set stylesheet to whole `MainWindow` I can get proper font information with `font()` method for all the widgets that `MainWindow` contains. But, when I set stylesheet to instance of `QApplication` the `font()` method for all the widgets return default font or the font previously set by `setFont()`. Why so?

Comment: Are you creating your widget in Qt Designer?

Comment: I set custom stylesheet to whole application. This stylesheet describe style of several widgets on my application. Thus, for example, I set custom background color and font for all QGraphicsView objects in my application:

app.setStyleSheet("font-family: Arial;font-style: normal;font-size: 12pt;font-weight: bold;");

Comment: Did you find the way?

Comment: In general, no. I can set the the same font for some widget that I set with stylesheet by using `setFont()` method. After this I can get this font and make all the required calculations. But I need to be sure that font set with stylesheet and set with `setFont()` method are identical. This approach required some extra synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load values from Qt Stylesheet you should call this methods:

```
widget->style()->unpolish(widget);
widget->style()->polish(widget);
widget->update();
```

After this all values of your widget will be updated according your stylesheet values specified.

Comment: The only necessary call is `QWidget::ensurePolished()`. There's absolutely no reason to explicitly re-polish the widget, nor to `update` it.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve a font of a specific widget reading it's properties, as the following:

```
//Get pushbutton font.
QFont font = ui->pushButton->property("font").value<QFont>();
qDebug() << font.family() << font.pointSize();

//Get MainWindow font.
QFont font2 = property("font").value<QFont>();
qDebug() << font2.family() << font2.pointSize();
```

Comment: As I found:

    QFont font = ui->pushButton->property("font").value<QFont>();

and    

    QFont font = ui->pushButton->font();

are equal.

Comment: That method is also useful to get the font size set when the user hits CTRL++ or CTRL+- to zoom in/out the fonts in a Qt application.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can tell from [QStyleSheetStyle::updateStyleSheetFont](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp.html#_ZNK16QStyleSheetStyle20updateStyleSheetFontEP7QWidget), the widget always contains the resolved font from the stylesheet. I'd expect `QWidget::font()` to return the resolved font that you've set using the stylesheet - i.e. the font that is the merged application font, any parent widget fonts, and the stylesheet font.

The widget must be polished first, of course, unless you're querying after the events have been delivered (i.e. from within the event loop).

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/style-font-query-test-45422885
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QLabel label("Test");
   auto font1 = label.font();
   label.setStyleSheet("font-size: 49pt;");
   label.show();
   label.ensurePolished();
   auto font2 = label.font();
   Q_ASSERT(font1.pointSize() != 49);
   Q_ASSERT(font2.pointSize() == 49);
   Q_ASSERT(font1.family() == font2.family());
}
```